# Improve speed cross-mapping array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, hash

just looking for a little help with a conversion from Perl to PHP. I utilized hashes to map values as keys across two arrays read in from two files. The files I am using aren't very big, roughly 150,000 rows in one, and 50,000 in the other. In Perl, this runs in roughly 10 seconds, but in PHP I've reduced the read-in file from 150,000 rows to around 20,000 rows and it takes nearly 3 minutes. I'm wondering if this is a limitation of the language or if my design is inherently flawed.

the two existing array of arrays are $ao_hash and $string_hash, built as follows:

```
// Load file contents
$file_contents = str_replace("\t","|",file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$file_array = explode("\n",$file_contents);

// Pass client dictionary into an array of arrays
foreach ($file_array as $line) {
    $line_array = explode("|",$line);
    if (stripos($line_array[0], 'mnemonic') !== false) { 
        continue; 
    }

    if (!isset($line_array[1])) {
        continue;
    }

    if (stripos($line_array[1], 'n') !== false) {
        continue;
    }

    if (!isset($line_array[10])) {
        continue;
    }

    $ao_hash[$line_array[10]] = $line;
}
```

Both hashes are built using this method, and both work well (expected results, quick execution). It reads like this:

```
$array1[NDC] = some|delimited|file|output
$array2[NDC] = another|file|with|delimited|output
```

I'm using NDC as the primary key to cross-map both arrays.

```
// Compare the client's drug report against the cut-down file
while (list ($key, $value) = each ($ao_hash)) {

    // Use the NDC to match across array of arrays
    if (isset($string_hash[substr($key,0,11)])) {
        $string_selector = $string_hash[substr($key,0,11)];
    }

    // Check if the client NDC entry exists in cut-down file
    if (!isset($string_selector)) {

        // No direct NDC match, reserve for an FSV look-up
        $ao_array = explode("|", $value);
        if (isset($ao_array[2]) && isset($ao_array[16])) {
            $no_matches[$ao_array[2].'|'.$ao_array[16]]['NDC'] = $ao_array[10];
            $no_matches[$ao_array[2].'|'.$ao_array[16]]['MNEMONIC'] = $ao_array[0];
        }
    } else {

        // Direct match found
        $ao_array = explode("|", $value);
        $cutdown_array = explode("|", $value);
        foreach ($cutdown_array as $cutdown_col) {
            if ($cutdown_col == "") {
                $cutdown_col = "0";
            }
            $cutdown_verified[] = $cutdown_col;
        }

        // Drop the last column
        array_pop($cutdown_verified);

        // Merge into a single string
        $final_string = implode("|", $cutdown_verified);

        // Prepare data for FSV match
        if (isset($ao_array[2]) && isset($ao_array[16])) {
            $yes_matches[$ao_array[2].'|'.$ao_array[16]]['DRUG_STRING'] = $final_string;
        }

        // Add the mnemonic to the end
        $final_string .= '|'.$ao_array[0];
        $drug_map[$ao_array[0]] = $final_string;
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome, would just like this to run faster.

Comment: I haven't done any tests, but there are a couple things that stand out to me as micro-optimizations and just general questions I have. The uploaded files appears to be a CSV, or a tab separated list. Have you tried using `fgetcsv` or `str_getcsv`? Next, you're only matching on the first 10 characters in your key. Rather than storing the entire key, just store the first 10 characters, this will save 2 substr(not much). Rather than storing the string in the map, why not store the array. THis will reduce explode calls.

Comment: It's a pipe delimited text file, but I wanted to catch tab delimited files (the users exporting from Excel don't always know to switch to pipe).

I can't substr to store the key, because the NDC might have a 12th value (like A or B) which I need to distinguish later one. I'll take a look to see if I can reduce the micro-edits.

I'll see if I can reduce explode calls. In Perl split/join calls are easily abused since they are relatively quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redditor https://www.reddit.com/user/the_alias_of_andrea solved the issue:

Instead of using:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($ao_hash))
```

it would be more efficient to use

```
foreach ($ao_hash as $key => $value)
```

Now a 13MB file executes immediately and I get the expected results.